# Merge 'rss-reader' and 'rss' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

We have the tags [rss](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) (x10) and [rss-reader](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss-reader) (x5). As the focus of our site is neither in developing RSS Feeds, nor in recommending good ones, nor in trouble-shooting the *feeds* (which again would belong to the development category), this leaves issues with RSS reading apps -- so both tags, in relation to our site, must be synonyms (correct me if I'm wrong).

Hence I suggest to merge the two, making one of them a synonym to the other. I'm totally free to which one should become the master :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's an actual app called "RSS Reader" that will be the source of questions, this seems like a reasonable merger to me.

Although, honestly, the question counts are so low we should just edit them. If the tag resurfaces later then let's create a synonym.

Comment: Actually, there are a bunch of apps having this in their name. Most of them use an identifying prefix (like "Easy RSS Reader", "Mobo RSS Reader"). Unfortunately there's also one just called "[RSS Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hchina.rssreader)" (took its author a lot of imagination to name it, I guess). I'm not sure if that should count as an excuse, as it's not the most popular one (last updated 07/2012, and 19 votes altogether). I checked all the languages supported by Play, and only found a single comment (French).

Comment: Then it's unlikely to generate questions here, so we can safely ignore it.